# FragmentTransaction show() hide () issue

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have a bottom navigation bar with 4 menu items, I use `FragmentTransaction` `show() , hide()` methods to switch between fragments on tabs click , hide current fragment and show next fragment,
Before using show or hide method I must add fragment first and then use show or hide , until now everything work fine and fragment show with it's final state that's what I want.
But last added fragment with `FragmentTransaction` `add()` method is always active and it's view still clickable and switched fragment not clickable or touched.
I don't know why this happen .. any advice ?!!

This my code

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment == null || fragment == currentFragment) return;

    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.fade_in_transaction,
            R.anim.fade_out_transaction
    );

    if (currentFragment != null && !currentFragment.isHidden()) {
        fragTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }
    Fragment savedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    if (savedFragment == null) {
        fragTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment
                , fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        this.currentFragment = fragment;
    } else {
        if (savedFragment.isHidden()) {
            fragTransaction.show(savedFragment);
        }
        this.currentFragment = savedFragment;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment() == null) {
        if (fragment instanceof FragmentHome) {
            fragTransaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
        }
    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Yes of course check edited post